# How to interpret this pmf and likelihood? From 'The Bayesian Choice by Christian Robert

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, likelihood, posterior

I'm having some difficulties in understanding the definitions in the following example:

[image]

How do we interpret the pmf and the likelihood? is it always 1/3? If so, then why the branching out for values of theta? Berger and Wolpert (1988) is compilation of lecture notes, and I have no access to it. Also what's the meaning of $\mathbb{N}^*$? I've never seen this notation. This example is from '[The Bayesian Choice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983)' by Christian Robert.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers to your questions about that admittedly rather artificial example:

> How do we interpret the pmf and the likelihood?

The pmf is the probability density of $X$ against the counting measure over the positive integers. Depending on the parity of $\theta$, i.e., whether it is odd or even, $X$ has a different support with three possible values, all with equal probabilities.

The likelihood is a function of the parameter $\theta$ indexed by the value of the realisation $x$ of $X$. It is zero except for three values of $\theta$ depending on $x$. This can be interpreted as a case where there are three and only three values of $\theta$ which are compatible with this realisation or equivalently which can lead to this realisation.

> is it always 1/3?

The functions are equal to $1/3$ for three entries and zero everywhere else.

> If so, then why the branching out for values of theta?

The density is defined on a different support of three integers for each value of $\theta$ and this support is described differently for odd and even values of $\theta$.

> Berger and Wolpert (1988) is compilation of lecture notes, and I have no access to it.

The entire [monograph](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215466210) is [available](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215466210) for free on [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215466210).

> Also what's the meaning of $ℕ^∗$?

This is a [standard notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402248/14893) for the set of [positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402248/14893).

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way, the monograph doesn't seem to be free. Maybe it's from where I am.

Comment: Surprising, it is indeed free on my connection from home.